# Injecting c# type into Ironpython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

Right now I can use following code to access my `c#` types in `IronPython` as follow

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('myDLL.dll')
import myType
obj = myType()
```

however I don't want script developers to have `clr.AddReference('myDLL.dll')` line in `Python` source code, and inject `myDLL.dll` (and/or a `c#` class) directly from `c#` into ScriptEngine so the previous code will be something similar to:

```
import myType

obj = myType()
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps distribute a python module with your dll that does the `AddReference` and imports `myType`. So users of your lib would only import the extra python module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this problem using following solution :

```
ScriptRuntime runtime = Python.CreateRuntime();
runtime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyNameSpace.MyClass)));
ScriptEngine eng = runtime.GetEngine("py");
ScriptScope scope = eng.CreateScope();
ScriptSource src = eng.CreateScriptSourceFromString(MySource, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
var result = src.Execute(scope);
```

Now, in python script you can write:

```
from MyNameSpace import *
n=MyClass()
print n.DoSomeThing()
```